# Multi VPS servers with monero installed for remote connections. Monero Gateway Redirection?

Tags: daemon, remote-node, server

I have a few VPS servers with monero installed. I use these servers when connecting from my desktop or mobile wallet. Every now and then they fail for whatever reason and require a restart. Is there a way to setup some type of gateway server that just redirects to a random VPS server I own when connecting to the gateway? What is this called exactly where you connect to one ip but that ip just redirects you to another ip at random?

I want to be able to goto something like this:

2.2.2.2/get_info

but gets redirected to one of these at random:

3.3.3.3/get_info

4.4.4.4/get_info

5.5.5.5/get_info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can setup a load balancer using tomcat or nginx.
- round robin will choose a random host to forward your request to.
- you can setup what's called a health check to add and remove hosts as they fail. a health check makes a request to your hosts behind the load balancer to for example /get_info, if it doesn't receive a response then it know it's not healthy.

You'll have to do a lot of this research yourself on the exact steps. This is definitely outside the scope of monero.

Comment: Round-robin is not random, it's sequential.